# Integrating Custom Data Flow Component for Package SSIS in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, business-intelligence, bids

I am facing a huge problem in SSIS package. I am currently migrating SSIS packages from 2008 to 2012. One of the SSIS packages uses the custom data flow component called "Error Output's Description" of Rémi Pestre. In fact this component manage error logs in SSIS packages.

I receive "PerformUpgrade Error" and "Impossible to update metadata of the component Error Description" when I open packages in visual studio 2012.

I tried to install the ErrorOutputDescription.dll using gacutil.exe. But it didn't work and I can not see the custom component in visual studio SSIS toolbox.

Could you please explain me how to install this DLL in 2012 environment ?

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to add the custom component Error Output Description in my Visual Studio 2012's SSIS toolbox. In fact, I tried to recompile and add in my assemblies and refresh the toolbox, it didn't work. Then I retried to use the DLL provided by Remi (cf his codeplex website), it worked.

Maybe I am a magician or visual studio 2012 is very weak but it works.

FYI, component details: Pestre.SqlServer.SSIS.DataFlowComponent.ErrorOutputDescription, ErrorOutputDescription, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97ab4c916d7328ad

[image]